# what are the %Field in returned list from web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm starting my journey in the web web service world, please excuse me if my question is very noob.

After calling web service, I got the result in a List object that I defined, but the strange thing for me is that every entry in the list is duplicated, the real one (which I defined) and the other new one with +"Field", like:

```
aStatus.Result
```

and

```
aStatus.resultField
```

Please see the attached image,
my question is what is the %Field, and why its coming?

[image: Returned result from webservice]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are simply the private backing fields for the public properties, so nothing to worry about. In the C# code generated by Visual Studio for the web service proxy you will see things like this:

```
private string subscriptionPINField;

public string SubscriptionPIN
{
    get
    {
        return this.subscriptionPINField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.subscriptionPINField = value;
    }
}
```